# What does Club Sets completion in Super Rush mean?

Tags: mario-golf-super-rush

My "Standard" clubs are 16/16 but my Star and Super Star say 1/16. What do the numbers represent? How do I get them to 16/16?

[image: Screenshot of in game stats, showing the different Club Sets]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [some website](https://gamerjournalist.com/mario-golf-super-rush-unlock-star-and-super-star-clubs/) I found by searching up `mario golf super star` on a search engine, you need to get 1,000 and 3,000 Character Points, which allow you to respectively unlock the two best Club sets for a character (the Star Club and the Super Star Club).

Since there's 16 characters, it seems that you've unlocked the two clubs for the character you play the most, and you have yet to unlock them for the 15 other characters.

[Another website](https://ag.hyperxgaming.com/article/11881/how-to-get-star-clubs-in-mario-golf-super-rush) mentions that you get points as you perform some actions:

- Play a hole: 10 points (even if you don't complete it, apparently).
- Collect a coin in Speed Golf: 3 points
- Birdie: 10 points (if you complete a hole with one less hit than displayed)
- Eagle: 20 points (if you complete a hole with two less hit than displayed)
- Albatross: 50 points (if you complete a hole with three less hit than displayed)
- Hole in one: 100 points (if you complete a hole in a single hit)